# How to run multi commands in one sh file?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, sh

I have a mac os and 
my question is about 'How to run multi commands in one sh file?', like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp 
open domain.com
user
pass
cd /public_html/test_folder
lcd /Users/mac/downloads
mput file
a
```

This commands for :

1. open ftp
2. connect to my website
3. enter user name
4. enter password
5. cd << for open folder in my website
6. lcd << open folder in my computer
7. mput << upload file from my computer
8. a << for question in ftp for file type or something like this

   I add `&&` in end each line but no work he start and stop in command line number 2

    I'm sorry for my bad language :(

Comment: Found this link pretty quickly with a Google search. It may be of interest to you: [How to use ftp in a shell script](http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lftp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lftp), very good in ftp scripting, when you require reconnect+continue file transfer, `ssh/scp` transfer, etc.

It should be similar to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
## note: mput: -c (retry+continue); run: lftp -c 'help mput' to see help
lftp -c 'mput -c -O ftp://name:passd@server.com/path/ file1.txt file2.txt'
```

Alternatively, you can write `lftp` scripts, example (note: `mirror -R` = upload):

```
#!/usr/bin/lftp -f
open ftp://ftp.server.com
user name passwd
cd /remote/path
lcd /local/path
mirror -R folder
```